# The best way to use Infinity in java to avoid double type?

Tags: java, integer, double

If I want to have a target `Integer` number that I want to initialized as infinity, Am I forced to use the `Double` type to begin with?

```
Integer min_val(List<Integer> nums) {

    double min_so_far = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

    for (Integer i : nums) {
        if (i < min_so_far) {
            min_so_far = (double) i;
        }
    }
    return (int) min_so_far;
}
```

For example, this `min` function above, I was looking for the minimum integer in a `List<Integer>`. I have to started with the `min_so_far` as `double`, then force convert every `int` in the `nums` to `double`, and then convert it back to `int` for return?

It seems quite redundant, not sure if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: always depends on what you actually want to do. For this, you could assume the first value as minimum and then just check if any other value is below that one

Comment: I think the answer is helpful in your case :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952024/how-to-implement-infinity-in-java

Comment: The key question here is: What do you want `min_val` to return if `nums` is empty? Since you're returning `Integer` (not `int`), I'd be tempted to return `null` in that case (except I probably wouldn't use `Integer`, but I'm guessing you have a reason), which would affect how you'd approach it...

Comment: I think this answer is helpful in your case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952024/how-to-implement-infinity-in-java

Comment: See the linked question's answers, specifically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17973014/157247) about integers (not doubles).

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is this example. No need for infinity. After all, the minimum value can't be higher than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

```
int min_so_far = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Comment: That is quite smart of an idea

Comment: Be careful. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is a possible value of an `int`. If you do this, you will not be able to distinguish between it being the smallest (only) element of `nums` and `nums` being empty.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan  if `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is the only element of `nums`, this will work. But if` nums` is empty, it won't, I am here to use this as an example, not to really re-invent the `Collections.min`