# Counting power sets with very large arrays, Java?‽

Tags: java, arrays, math, numbers, biginteger

I am doing the following programming exercise: [Counting power sets](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54381f0b6f032f933c000108). The statement is:

> In this kata, you must create a function powers/Powers that takes an
> array, and returns the number of subsets possible to create from that
> list. In other words, counts the power sets.
>
> For instance
>
> powers([1,2,3]) => 8
>
> ...due to...
>
> powers([1,2,3]) => [[],  [1](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54381f0b6f032f933c000108),  [2],  [3],  [1,2],  [2,3],  [1,3],
> [1,2,3]]
>
> Your function should be able to count sets up to the size of 500, so
> watch out; pretty big numbers occur there!
>
> For comparison, my Haskell solution can compute the number of sets for
> an array of length 90 000 in less than a second, so be quick!
>
> You should treat each array passed as a set of unique values for this
> kata.
>
> #### Examples:
>
> Powers.powers(new int[]{});        // 1 Powers.powers(new int[]{1});
> // 2 Powers.powers(new int[]{1,2});     // 4 Powers.powers(new
> int[]{1,2,3,4}); // 16

I have written the following answer:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;
public class Powers {
  public static BigInteger powers/**/(int[] list) {
    System.out.println("list: "+Arrays.toString(list));
    System.out.println("list length: "+list.length);
    double pow = Math.pow(2, list.length);
    System.out.println("pow: "+pow);
    return new BigInteger(String.valueOf((long)pow));
  }
}
```

However for a 100 array it does not output the expected result. For example, for the following array:

```
list: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list length: 100
```

It outputs:

```
9223372036854775807
```

Instead of:

```
1267650600228229401496703205376
```

I thought the difficulty was generated by rounnding the pow result from double to long, because of it outputs:

```
pow: 1.2676506002282294E30
```

Then I tried to use modPow to be able to get results with bigger numbers:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Powers {
  public static BigInteger powers/**/(int[] list) {
    System.out.println("list: "+Arrays.toString(list));
    System.out.println("list length: "+list.length);
    BigInteger pow = BigInteger.valueOf(2).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(list.length), BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE));
    System.out.println("pow: "+pow);
    return new BigInteger(String.valueOf(pow));
  }
}
```

However when we test with the 100 length array, the output is:

```
137438953472
```

When it should be:

```
1267650600228229401496703205376
```

I think the challenge is due to Long.MAX_VALUE is equal than the highest value being calculated by modPow, because of it outputs:

```
pow: 137438953472
```

After that I tried to write a higher number for modulus inside modPow function and I wrote this:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Powers {
  public static BigInteger powers/**/(int[] list) {
    System.out.println("list: "+Arrays.toString(list));
    System.out.println("list length: "+list.length);
    BigInteger modulus = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY).toBigInteger();
    BigInteger pow = BigInteger.valueOf(2).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(list.length), modulus);
    System.out.println("pow: "+pow);
    return new BigInteger(String.valueOf(pow));
  }
}
```

However the following exception is being thrown:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Character I is neither a decimal digit number, decimal point, nor "e" notation exponential mark.
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:518)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:401)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:834)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(BigDecimal.java:1304)
    at Powers.powers(Powers.java:7)
```

I think it is generated because of Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY gives us a bigger number than the highest being represented by BigInteger.

So as a result, the first two codes could pass the following tests:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class PowersTest {
    
  @Test
  public void testPactical() {
    assertEquals("An empty array should return 1!", Powers.powers(new int[]{}), BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    assertEquals(Powers.powers(new int[]{1}), BigInteger.valueOf(2));
    assertEquals(Powers.powers(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}), BigInteger.valueOf(32));
  }
  
}
```

However both codes, have difficulties to pass the 100 length array test.

In addition I have read:

- [BigInteger.pow(BigInteger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582277/biginteger-powbiginteger)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger)
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_modpow.htm
- [What does BigInteger having no limit mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088436/what-does-biginteger-having-no-limit-mean)
- [How to implement infinity in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952024/how-to-implement-infinity-in-java/17973014)

Could you help me to find out how to count power sets with very large arrays in Java?‽

EDIT:

It is solved by writting:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Powers {
  public static BigInteger powers/**/(int[] list) {
    return BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(list.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(list.length));

Comment: Yes @emil you are right, if we use BigInteger.pow() it outputs the expected output, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Actually it would be more efficient to call: `BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(list.length)`. --- On my machine, with `list.length = 90000`, it builds a 27093 digit string in about 0.04 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Um... I checked and I think this works:

```
public static BigInteger powers(int[] list) {
    return BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(list.length);
  }
```