# How to add an item to start of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and I have an array

```
int [] A = {140,150,160,170,180,190}
```

I need to add infinity at the beginning of the array

like so:

```
int [] A = {inf,140,150,160,170,180,190}
```

I know from Python to do it like so:

```
A=[140,150,160,170,180,190]
A=[float('inf')]+A
```

I need a way to do that in Java as simple as Python without loops

It's important to say I need the array / list(A=[140,150,160,170,180,190]) to be given with the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement infinity in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952024/how-to-implement-infinity-in-java)

Comment: You can't do this, because a Java `int` doesn't support infinity as a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java ArrayList that implements [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface and has a method `add(int,E)`
So, you can use something like `list.add(0, myObj);`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

is there an option to write the list to begin with?
something like:
List list = new ArrayList(140,150,160,170);

Comment: List<Integer> arrayInt = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));